# Adding sticky note one behind another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Thanks in advance, I am trying add sticky images one behind another as shown in below image, but am getting the result as one below another. Latest added sticky note should be on top, all other notes are to be behind the latest. Any help would be appreiated.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.pink{
 background:#f05f9d;
 border:1px solid #f05f9d;
 color:#fff;
 font-weight:600;
}
.pink:hover{
 background:#f05f9d;
 border:1px solid #f05f9d;
 color:#fff;
 font-weight:600;
}
.pink-button{
 padding: 10px 11px;
 border-radius: 14px;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 16px;
}
.sticky {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 8px 24px;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 border:1px #E8Ds47 solid;
 -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 6px 1px #333333;
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 6px 1px #333333;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 6px 1px #333333;
 background: #fefdca;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fefdca), color-stop(100%,#f7f381)); 
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fefdca', endColorstr='#f7f381',GradientType=0 ); 
 background: linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%);
}
.sticky p {
 text-align: center;
}
.sticky textarea {
 width:160px;
 height:170px;
 background: #fefdca;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fefdca), color-stop(100%,#f7f381)); 
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fefdca', endColorstr='#f7f381',GradientType=0 );
 background: linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%);
 border-bottom:none !important;
}
.sticky ol {
 margin: 12px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sticky">
  <textarea placeholder="Type the problem here..."></textarea>    
</div><br/>  
<div id="spin_btn_div">
    <div class="btn-container" style="margin-bottom:0px;position:absolute;margin-left:40px;">
      <a class="btn pink pink-button shooter-btn" id="addProblem">Add problem</a>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
$('#addProblem').click(function(){
 $('.sticky').after('<div class="sticky"><textarea placeholder="Type the problem here..."></textarea><br></div>');
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to set `.sticky` as `position: absolute;` then set `position: relative;` on theirs parent, after that play with their `z-index` and `left/right` properties.

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/x7cqphq9/

Comment: Hmm, perfect..., But it is adding like one above another, i trying to get as one behind another like in above image...!

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/x7cqphq9/1/
I've set some custom `z-index` your first `.sticky`, which is resides in HTML, has and then I'm getting this default value and for the sequential elements I decrement this `z-index` by 1

Comment: Again Thank u...! but here i want latest added note should be on top, here in your fiddle example latest added note is staying behind the old one..! Even am trying that too

Comment: Have u check my answer?

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo  yeah, Thank u... but multiple sticky notes are adding when i click add button third time..!

Comment: Anyway Thank u Dude @Krusader, With some changes, it works..!

Answer (score 1):

Position you sticky and place it inside a container. Then assign `left` value based on the `.sticky` count. check below snippet.

```js
$('#addProblem').click(function() {
  $('.sticky').after('<div class="sticky"><textarea placeholder="Type the problem here..."></textarea><br></div>');
  var stickyCount = $('.sticky').length - 1;
  $('.sticky').each(function() {
    $(this).css('left', stickyCount * 100);
    stickyCount--;
  });
});
```

```css
.pink {
  background: #f05f9d;
  border: 1px solid #f05f9d;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.pink:hover {
  background: #f05f9d;
  border: 1px solid #f05f9d;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.pink-button {
  padding: 10px 11px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  border: 1px #E8Ds47 solid;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px #333333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px #333333;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px #333333;
  background: #fefdca;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fefdca), color-stop(100%, #f7f381));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fefdca', endColorstr='#f7f381', GradientType=0);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
}

.sticky p {
  text-align: center;
}

.sticky textarea {
  width: 160px;
  height: 170px;
  background: #fefdca;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fefdca), color-stop(100%, #f7f381));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fefdca', endColorstr='#f7f381', GradientType=0);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
  border-bottom: none !important;
}

.sticky ol {
  margin: 12px;
}

.sticky-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 250px;
}

.sticky {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sticky-container">
  <div class="sticky">
    <textarea placeholder="Type the problem here..."></textarea>
  </div>
</div><br/>
<div id="spin_btn_div">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <a class="btn pink pink-button shooter-btn" id="addProblem">Add problem</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank u... but multiple sticky notes are adding when i click add button third time..!

Comment: Awesome bro..! I just made some changes in your code, Finally it works, you really deserves a up vote...!

Comment: @GaneshPutta Hope that messy is followed from your code snippet.

Comment: Yeah, Thank u...!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version

HTML:

```
<section class="sticky-wrapper">
   <div class="sticky">
   <textarea placeholder="Type the problem here..."></textarea>             
   </div>
</section>
<br/>
<div id="spin_btn_div">
  <div class="btn-container">
  <a class="btn pink pink-button shooter-btn" id="addProblem">Add problem</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sticky-wrapper {
   position: relative;
   min-height: 300px;
}

.pink{
   background:#f05f9d;
   border:1px solid #f05f9d;
   color:#fff;
   font-weight:600;
}

.pink:hover{
   background:#f05f9d;
   border:1px solid #f05f9d;
   color:#fff;
   font-weight:600;
}
.pink-button{
   padding: 10px 11px;
   border-radius: 14px;
   font-weight: 600;
   font-size: 16px;
}
.sticky {
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 8px 24px;
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   font-size: 1.4em;
   border:1px #E8Ds47 solid;
   -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 6px 1px #333333;
   -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 6px 1px #333333;
   box-shadow:0px 0px 6px 1px #333333;
   background: #fefdca;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fefdca), color-stop(100%,#f7f381)); 
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fefdca', endColorstr='#f7f381',GradientType=0 ); 
   background: linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%);
}
 .sticky p {
   text-align: center;
}
.sticky textarea {
   width:160px;
   height:170px;
   background: #fefdca;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fefdca), color-stop(100%,#f7f381)); 
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fefdca', endColorstr='#f7f381',GradientType=0 );
   background: linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%);
   border-bottom:none !important;
}
.sticky ol {
   margin: 12px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var zIndex = 0;
var currentXPosition = 0;

$('#addProblem').click(function(){

   zIndex++;

  $('.sticky-wrapper').append('<div class="sticky" style="z-index: ' + zIndex +'; left: 0px"><textarea placeholder="Type the problem here..."></textarea><br></div>');


   $(".sticky-wrapper").find(".sticky:not(:last-child)").each(function (i, item) {
       var itemLeftPos = parseInt(item.style.left || 0);
       currentXPosition = 100; 
       item.style.left = (itemLeftPos + currentXPosition) + "px";
    });

});
```

Note: I've added wrapper element with class `.sticky-wrapper`.
[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7cqphq9/3/)